# Execution not returning after calling API succesfully

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, http-delete

While calling the Web API HttpDelete API endpoint from MVC Controller, execution is not returning back to the controller

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.DeleteAsync(new Uri($"{AppSettingsHelper.GetValue("ApiHost")}/api/delete/user/{userId}"));
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Result and execution should be return back to the MVC controller

Comment: Can you post the code calling this?

Comment: Suffix DeleteAsync with 'ConfigureAwait(false)' and then give it a try.

Comment: @MandeepJanjua, why would `ConfigureAwait(false)` make this work? If it was working, it might make a difference.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Please refer to the upvoted answer for more details. It's hard to give recommendations w\o knowing how the above method is called or consumed. I suspected it's getting deadlocked while restoring the synchronization context

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the call chain you're probably calling `.Wait()` or `.Result` on a task. This is causing a deadlock because your scheduler won't release this async context until that task completes, but the task cannot complete without having access to the async context to handle the continuation of your task.

The best recommendation is usually to go "async all the way", using `async/await` patterns all the way from your controller action to this method.

If that's impossible, the next-best thing is to make sure you call `.ConfigureAwait(false)` every time you see an `await` keyword. But beware because if you do this and then try to access something like `HttpContext.Current` after one of these awaits, it'll fail.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` should not be used on action methods precisely for the reason you mention.

Comment: Do not want to assume a lot and also does not want to go beyond limits of the asked question - leaving this comment here in case someone else needs help - there are certain scenarios where you need to use ConfigureAwait and still be able to access HttpContext.Current. If that's the case for you then please leave a comment here and we'll take it from there.